# Sorting loop function creates infinite subdirectories

Tags: bash, loops, sorting

I routinely have to sort large amounts of images in multiple folders into two 2 file types, ".JPG" and ".CR2". I'm fairly new to bash but have created a basic script that will sort through one individual folder successfully and divide these file types into distinct folders.

I'm having problems scaling this up to automatically loop through subdirectories. My current script creates an infinite loop of new subfolders until terminal times out.

How can I use the loop function without having it cycle through new folders?

```
function f {
    cd "$1"
            count=`ls -1 *.JPG 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
                if [ $count != 0 ]; then 
                    echo true
                    mkdir JPG; mv *.JPG jpg
                else
                    echo false
                fi
            count=`ls -1 *.CR2 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
                if [ $count != 0 ]; then 
                    echo true
                    mkdir RAW; mv *.CR2 raw;
                else
                    echo false
                fi
    for d in * .[!.]* ..?*; do
        cd "$1"
        test -d "$1/$d" && f "$1/$d"
    done
}

f "`pwd`"
```

Comment: `mkdir JPG; mv *.JPG jpg` This is totally wrong or does your filesystem don't differentate big and small letters? Cause this create a directory `JPG` and then moves all files into `jpg` folder. Also `mkdir JPG` will fail, if the folder already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I still advise people to use `find` instead of globulation `*` in scripts. The `*` may not work reliably always, may fail and confuse.

First we create directories to move to:

```
mkdir -p ./jpg ./cr2
```

Note that `-p` in `mkdir` will make `mkdir` not fail in case the directory already exists.

Use `find`. Find all files named `*.JPG` and move each file to `jpg` :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.JPG' -exec mv {} ./jpg \;
// similar
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.CR2' -exec mv {} ./cr2 \;
```

The `-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1` is so that the `find` does not scan the directory recursively, which is the default. You can remove them, but  If you want, you can add `-type f` to include files only.

Notes to your script:

- [Don't parse ls output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- You can use the `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -file '*.jpg' -print . | wc -c` to get the number of files in a directory instead.
- `for d in * .[!.]* ..?*; do` I have a vague idea what this is supposed to do, some kind of recursively scanning the directory. Buf if the directory `JPG` is inside `$(pwd)` then you will scan infinitely into yourself and move the file into yourself etc... If the destination folder is outside current directory, just modify the `find` scripts by removing `-mindepth 1`, it will scan recursively then.
- Don't use backticks, they are less readable and [are deprecated](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). Use `$( .. )` instead.